# how to load application on button event of push notification in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, push-notification

I wanted to know whether it is possible to load the application or some specific page on clicking the "OK" button of the push notification or not in objective c.

As i want to load the application when i press the button of the push notification.Kindly help me out if possible.

Thanking you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the push notification usually have a "View" button that will automatically launch your application. you don't have to do anything in your app for that to work.

when the user launches the application that way, your app delegate receives a call to
`- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`,
the `launchOptions` dictionary containing whatever data was added to the push notification payload by the server.
you can check that and open any relevant page or view, or handle that notification anyway you want.

Comment: okay thank you, but can u tell me whether i can navigate directly to some specific page? I mean instead of launching the view controller can i load some ABC page?

Comment: Can i load the inner page with the click event of the view button of the APNS?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by "inner page", but anyway, yes, you can. You'll get the push notification data in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, so you can load anything you want right away.